# Read data from rfcomm0

Tags: java, ubuntu, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, rfcomm

I am using an RPi3 and has Ubuntu MATE running on it. I connected a Bluetooth device and I want to read data from the rfcomm0 port.

Since the device uses a special protocol, "cat /dev/rfcomm0" can show something but it is not readable. I want to write a java file that can read byte[] from rfcomm0. Is there any ways to reach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The device /dev/rfcomm0 will behave like a serial device. So you might want to use a Java Serial library to handle the settings of baud rates and the like.
See [Is there Java library or framework for accessing Serial ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747539/is-there-java-library-or-framework-for-accessing-serial-ports)

The other option is to set the serial parametes via commandline eg. with stty see 
[Set stty parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092791/set-stty-parameters)

The the device has been prepared you can then read and write to the device just as with any other file. Just open the device with a FileInputStream to do so.